# Email wont send with php

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send an email through php. I have tried sending to aol and hotmail accounts and no luck with either. Also firebug is returning me "mail sent" so i dont know what the problem is.

```
 $to = '$em';
 $subject = "Welcome";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nTest";
 $mail_sent = @mail($to, $subject, $body);
 echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

$em is an email address drawn from a database and i have checked and $em is defiantly equal to an email address

Comment: Have you checked the SMTP logs? Have you checked your spam folder? Also don't suppress errors on mail. You need errors if something is wrong!

Comment: have you checked the spam folder in your hotmail account?

Comment: I recommend removing the `@` from your `mail` call and posting the reported error message.

Comment: Just try: mail("whatever@whatever.com", "My Email Test", "Testing 123"); and see what happens - boil it down to the basics, get it to work, THEN start making more complex.

Comment: are you trying to send e-mail from localhost server or a page on server?? because as far I know you can't send emails from localhost on your PC

Comment: SzamDev - I'm sending from a page on a server not localhost
Dave and Chomp - i Tried back to basics and still no luck with an email coming through to hotmail or aol again
Khez and Khez - I've checked the spam folder, no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two big problems here.  Let's break it down.

```
$to = '$em';
```

Variables are not interpolated inside of [single-quoted strings](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php).  If you need to assign `$to` to the value inside `$em`, then ditch the quotes:  `$to = $em;`

```
$mail_sent = @mail($to, $subject, $body);
echo $mail_sent ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

[The `@` is an error silencing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).  Using it is bad practice, because it stops PHP from letting you know when something goes wrong.  Ditch it.

Not that suppressing errors helps here, as [`mail()` is *functionally retarded*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) and *never actually complains* when something *might* have gone wrong.

> Also firebug is returning me "mail sent" so i dont know what the problem is.

When `mail()` returns true, as it has here, it means that PHP *thinks* that the mail was sent.

That doesn't mean it actually *was* sent.  `mail()` is a black box.  Once it thinks it's succeeded, the mail is somewhere else and you have no way to check on it.

Please look into using your web hosting provider's SMTP server and [a modern PHP mail library, like SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/).  SwiftMailer is a bit more complex to use, but [is pretty straight-forward](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/message-quickref) to get working.  [The documentation](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction) is excellent.

By using a modern mail library that doesn't use `mail`, you will be able to see any errors along the way and deal with them.  It will also enable you to know that your message *was* sent, meaning you can follow up with your hosting provider and/or email provider to determine why the message was not delivered.